# why button support both RoutedEvent and command?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I happened to see the reference source code of buttonbase.cs:

```
    protected virtual void OnClick()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEvent = new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, this); 
        RaiseEvent(newEvent);

        MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.ExecuteCommandSource(this); 
    }
```

I know the first rountedevent is when I generate a event handler in Properties window, and the second one is a command binding I add in xaml.

I'm curious why button support both 2 mechanisms.
Can I say the first one is for backward compatibility and the second one is recommended in MVVM world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it backward compatibility since both were introduced in .NET 3.0. Commands are better for most use cases in MVVM, but you cannot say that there are no use cases for routed events. There are even cases in which you might want to use routed commands. It is up to the coder to decide which one is most suitable.

May I suggest [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)?